# How to test an unsigned Firefox extension?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon

Firefox 43 now enforces add-on signing. I don't understand how one is to test and debug an extension in these versions of Firefox prior to having the extension signed.

If I'm writing a new extension, how do I go about testing the unsigned version in the latest versions of Firefox? Is there an explicit way to disable the signing enforcement for developers?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Define 'latest version'?

- In FF43-FF45 or developer edition/nightly you can set `xpinstall.signatures.required` to false in `about:config`
- In FF45 (currently dev edition) you can load the addon as temporary in `about:debugging`
- In FF46 `xpinstall.signatures.required` is [removed](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2016/01/22/add-on-signing-update/).

Mozilla [was supposed to](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Addons/Extension_Signing#FAQ) release an [unofficial 'unbranded' versions](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1135781) that still has this preference but it [does not seem like this is actually happening](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1200346#c4).

---

My suggestion:

1. Download [Firefox Developer Edition](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/channel/#developer)
2. - a) flip `xpinstall.signatures.required`;
   - b) load the addon as temporary

Comment: Note: based on testing in FF44 at least up to beta 8, `xpinstall.signatures.required` = `false` is still valid and functional. It may go away in FF45, but we will not actually know until that hits beta (as it is *supposed to be* unnecessary to disable the requirement in all pre-beta releases).

Comment: @Makyen they keep changing their plans all the time

Comment: Yeah, they do and they don't keep the public and add-on developers updated as to what the plans are when they change, or slip. The way they have handled this, and a few other things regarding extensions recently, is, in my opinion, very poor. Unfortunately, the best we can do is keep updating answers with the information we have available.

Comment: Hopefully you should soon be able to use an [official Docker image](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium/pull/679) for this.

Answer (score 1):

If it's with addon sdk, there is a `jpm sign` command. There is also a signing API - http://olympia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/api/signing.html

- Run the `jpm sign --api-key KEY --api-secret SECRET` command. This will
  create a signed xpi and upload it to AMO as an "unlisted" extension.
  Then you'll find a `****.xpi` file in the current
  directory.  FF 43+
  will allow it to be installed.

To test it, you'll have to rely on dev/nightly channels. The unbranded builds I haven't seen yet. There is an ongoing discussion on how people can actually test their addon which has a bug in say release/beta channel, on the release/beta channel.

Also dogfooding typically is done by other users on release/beta channels. So its an ongoing discussion, but for dogfooding they recommend the `jpm sign` or the signing api.

A possible useful topic - https://github.com/diegocr/GitHubExtIns/issues/19

This blog has all we need to know on jpm sign - https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2015/12/18/signing-firefox-add-ons-with-jpm-sign/

Comment: Good finds! Now I'm asking myself what that signing-enforcement should be good for. Enhanced security sounds doubtful, if everyone and his little sister can self-sign (or the automated beta-signing is "taking place immediately"). So it's just more work for the dev – and a user no longer can "tamper" with some (no longer maintained) addon for simple fixes. Great stuff :(

Answer (score 1):

With Firefox 48 Mozilla introduced "Unbranded Builds" which allow you to install unsigned extensions. See [this blog post](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2016/07/29/extension-signing-availability-of-unbranded-builds/) or download them directly at [Add-ons/Extension Signing Wiki page](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Add-ons/Extension_Signing#Unbranded_Builds).

Answer (score 0):

Go to about:config and turn xpinstall.signatures.required

Comment: As [pointed out by minj](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34589808/2533433): *In FF46 `xpinstall.signatures.required` is [removed](https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2016/01/22/add-on-signing-update/)* – so your answer is no longer helpful.

Answer (score -1):

Install Waterfox. It is identical to Firefox, but allows unsigned extensions. You won't even know it is not regular Firefox. Problem solved.