# Why extensions(add-ons) of Mozilla Firefox is auto removing?

Tags: firefox-addon

I'm using Mozilla Firefox 43.0.4. Recently I've faced an irritating problem. After restart my computer, all  add-ons (Extensions) has removes automatically from the browser.This process has occurred as many times as I restart my computer. How can I solve this problem.

Comment: As stated, this question is off topic: Questions about **general computing hardware and software are off-topic** for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on [Super User](http://superuser.com/about).  It is possible that you are asking about your own personally developed Firefox add-ons. If the question was re-worded to state that then it might be on-topic.

Comment: Your question implies that you did not bother to click on the "[Learn more ...](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/add-on-signing-in-firefox?as=u&utm_source=inproduct)" link in the banner at the top of the page when you started Firefox, or the link on every disabled add-on in `about:adons` (and the multiple other links that linked page contains for more information).

Comment: It also appears that you did not make any attempt to search for an answer to this question, as the top 5 results of a [Google search for "Firefox 43 add-ons removes automatically from the browser"](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&lr=&as_qdr=all&q=Firefox+43+add-ons+removes+automatically+from+the+browser) all have relevant content about add-on signing. In addition, there are multiple recent posts on StackOverflow that have more than enough information in them to adequately answer your question, and your follow-on question in your comment below.

Comment: If your question is about signing your own add-ons, some relavent questions/answers: [Signing XUL-based add-on for Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33906756/signing-xul-based-add-on-for-firefox/33929935#33929935), [How to test an unsigned Firefox extension?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34439399/how-to-test-an-unsigned-firefox-extension), [How to Signing a Firefox Extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34608873/how-to-signing-a-firefox-extension).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Firefox 43 is requiring that addons be signed. This is a security measure to protect Firefox users. If the addon has not be signed by the developer, then it is being disabled.

Most addon developers are updating their addons, if someone hasn't please reach out to the developer and tell them to please update.

Comment: Thanks. Now I would like to know what is the way to signed?

Comment: The author of the addon has to upload to addons.mozilla.org - if they don't want it to be publicly listed then they can use the self sign api which makes the addon unlisted - https://blog.mozilla.org/addons/2015/12/18/signing-firefox-add-ons-with-jpm-sign/